# Jquery Validation Not Firing with No Errors in Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a small form with one field that I am trying to use to collect a zip code. I am trying to use Jquery Validate to make sure the field is not empty when submitted, but for some reason the validation is not firing and the form submits when the submit button is clicked even if the field is empty. I don't have any errors showing up in the console at all, and the id attribute for the form and the name attribute for the zip field are correct, so I'm at a loss for what the cause might be.

Here's my form code:

```
<form action="http://com.bluspero:8888/zip-locations" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" id="content-zip-form">
  <div style="display:none">
    <input type="hidden" name="init_gmap_search" value="y" />
    <input type="hidden" name="channel[]" value="locations" />
    <input type="hidden" name="distance" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="metric" value="miles" />
    <input type="hidden" name="geocode_field" value="cf_location" />
    <input type="hidden" name="distance_field" value="distance_max" />
    <input type="hidden" name="location" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="latitude_field" value="location_latitude" />
    <input type="hidden" name="longitude_field" value="location_longitude" />
    <input type="hidden" name="multiple_locations" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="site_url" value="http://com.bluspero:8888/" />
    <input type="hidden" name="required" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="secure_return" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ajax_response" value="n" />
    <input type="hidden" name="base_form_submit" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="/zip-locations" />
    <input type="hidden" name="XID" value="fd052500bb584ee4f741a5670f79e61846018091" />
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="fd052500bb584ee4f741a5670f79e61846018091" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-inline content-section-zip-form text-center">
    <p>
      <label class="control-label">Enter your Zip Code</label><br>
      <input type="text" class="form-control zip-field required" name="cf_location" id="cf_location">
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="distance_max" id="distance_max" value="">
    <p><button class="btn btn-bluspero" type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button></p>
  </div><!-- /input-group --> 

</form>
```

Here's my script code:

```
$('#content-zip-form').validate({
    invalidHandler : function(){
        $('button[type=submit]').attr('disabled',false);                
    },
    submitHandler : function(form){              
        //$(form).submit();
        alert('validation in place');
        return false;
    },
    rules : {
        cf_location: {required:true}           
    },

    errorElement: 'p',
    errorClass: "form-error",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo( element.parents(".content-section-zip-form"));
    }       
});
```

The javascript is inside a document ready call, inside one of my script files.

Unless I am completely mistaken, the submithandler in my validate script should prevent the form from submitting at all (I have it there ti try and fix this issue) but the form submits nonetheless. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

If you want to see this in an actual page, you can view it at http://bluspero.odysseydesignstudio.com/zip-locations

Comment: I do not see the form on the page you linked (I saw it one time few minutes ago)

Comment: Trying to debug for you, notice that if I try to call .rules() on your form its throwing an error. Might be a good starting place for you to dig into your code. It should return a list of rules already attached to the form if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: I've placed your code (along with the jquery validate code. Damn them for not having an HTTPS link for jsFiddle) in this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tg0b35u3/1/ . Supposedly works great. I looked at the documentation and everything you seem to be doing works too. I'm unsure what might be interfering from your other resources on the site, or if you might have an outdated version of something (like jQuery or jQuery Validation). Hopefully that jsFiddle will help with debugging.

Comment: @aurel.g sorry, I should have explained in the original post. The form is tied to  a map plugin that is part of the cms. When you run a search it stores a cookie that holds onto your last search and the way I have the page coded, once you've run the search it uses that cookie as the search parameter. You may need to view the page in incognito mode or you may need to dump the cookie after each submission. The cookie is named gmap_last_post.

Comment: @Brad Decker What is the actual syntax you used to call the rules? I tried it in the console and got an error, but I also got an error on a form that isn't having validation problems, so I think I must be entering it incorrectly.

Comment: @tredzko Thanks for setting that up. It is bizarre. I moved the code into a very simple template that had nothing but the form and the validation scripts and it works kist like on the jsFiddle. That makes me think there is some sort of Javascript conflict, but I've tried removing all the other scripts that aren't essential to validating the form and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @user1778246 No problem. Sometimes the best way to debug something is isolate it! :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone. I sorted out the problem. In the full page design I have a version of the zip code form in the header. On this particular page it has the form twice (2 different versions of the same form). It turns out the CMS caches the tag output and was attaching the form id to both forms on the page, so the second one wasn't firing the validation because it didn't have a valid id. Once I fixed that issue and adjusted the jquery accordingly it kicked on.

Answer (score 0):

Your rules/messages need to come first, then your submitHandler.

```js
$('#content-zip-form').validate({
  rules: {
    cf_location: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    cf_location: {
      required: "Enter a zipcode Please."
    }
  },
  invalidHandler: function() {
    $('button[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    //$(form).submit();
    alert('validation in place');
    return false;
  },
  errorElement: 'p',
  errorClass: "form-error",
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.appendTo(element.parents(".content-section-zip-form"));
  }
});
```

```css
p.form-error {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form action="http://com.bluspero:8888/zip-locations" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" id="content-zip-form">
  <div style="display:none">
    <input type="hidden" name="init_gmap_search" value="y" />
    <input type="hidden" name="channel[]" value="locations" />
    <input type="hidden" name="distance" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="metric" value="miles" />
    <input type="hidden" name="geocode_field" value="cf_location" />
    <input type="hidden" name="distance_field" value="distance_max" />
    <input type="hidden" name="location" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="latitude_field" value="location_latitude" />
    <input type="hidden" name="longitude_field" value="location_longitude" />
    <input type="hidden" name="multiple_locations" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="site_url" value="http://com.bluspero:8888/" />
    <input type="hidden" name="required" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="secure_return" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ajax_response" value="n" />
    <input type="hidden" name="base_form_submit" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="/zip-locations" />
    <input type="hidden" name="XID" value="fd052500bb584ee4f741a5670f79e61846018091" />
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="fd052500bb584ee4f741a5670f79e61846018091" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-inline content-section-zip-form text-center">
    <p>
      <label class="control-label">Enter your Zip Code</label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" class="form-control zip-field required" name="cf_location" id="cf_location">
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="distance_max" id="distance_max" value="">
    <p>
      <button class="btn btn-bluspero" type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- /input-group -->
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't appear to be the issue. I put the rules in first and it had no effect.